# Can I move the frame of UIKeyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uikeyboard

What I'm trying to do:

I'm using the same type of side-style menu that the new Facebook and Path apps use. Here's the code I'm basing it on: https://github.com/pkluz/ZUUIRevealController (click on the link for a picture too).

Basically, on my 'main' view, the keyboard is always shown. When I 'reveal' the side view, I would like the keyboard to slide away with the rest of the main view, as if the keyboard is attached to the main view. Currently, it just stays overlaying everything else.

-

Should I even attempt to figure out a way to achieve this? Or is the keyboard's frame locked down pretty tight?

Even better, if you can explain a way to do this, using the GitHub code I'm basing around - I would definitely give a bounty (can't set it yet though, as the question needs to be on for a few days)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved... turns out there's actually a very clean way to do it.

```
UIView * activeKeyboard = activeInputView.inputAccessoryView.superview;
activeKeyboard.frame = newFrame;
```

It's that easy. No undocumented API calls, but still crossing my fingers that it makes it through the approval process.

Keep in mind this code is just the important bit, there's other code around it etc to make it all happen - but that shouldn't be too hard to figure out if you need to achieve the same :)

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same effect using ZUUIRevealController (now PKRevealController). Would you be able to describe your surrounding code a bit more? My solution involves creating an inputAccessoryView to gain access to superview (the keyboard). I then remove the keyboard from its superview and then add it as a subview to my main view... but this seems a bit hackish.. I'm not messing with the frame at all.

Comment: @Jon that's pretty much what I do. I'm using a similar control to ZUUIRevealController. From memory, that's the crux of it - the hard part is making everything work perfectly, such as rotation etc and look good at the same time. Nothing that can't be done, no tricky hacks or anything -  but I'll leave that part to you :)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, I've experimented with something like this to replicate the behavior of the Messages app (where the user can drag the keyboard by scrolling the messages list).

That said, there is no officially-sanctioned way to do this, so any solution will likely be hacky and might break with OS updates.

The way I did it was basically to find the `UIWindow` that the keyboard sits in and modify its `transform` property. The keyboard window currently uses the private class `UITextEffectsWindow`, but this may change anytime, so I wouldn't rely on it. Even the fact that the keyboard is in a window that you can access at all (via `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]`) is not documented anywhere and could change.

I'm not sure if I would do anything like this in a released app. If you try, you have to code *very* defensively to ensure that it doesn't break if the implementation details of the keyboard change in the future.