# Is it possible to slide in the keyboard from the side, rather than the bottom

Tags: ios, uikeyboard, first-responder

When a control becomes the First Responder, normally the keyboard slides in from the bottom. How can I change that behavior and make it slide in from the left or the right instead? It makes much more sense for the particular UI that I'm working on.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could try to move the keyboard frame intercepting the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` event.
For retrieving the keyboard frame refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6457567/846273) or [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10957980/846273).

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own view which functions as a keyboard.

Comment: Are you serious? So you are suggesting that I replicate Apple's standard functionality of predictive text input, auto-correction, heuristics for adapting to imprecise touches (a field of AI), keys layout and touch animations for small, cap, symbols, languages, numbers, etc.. etc..??? You probably don't realize but the standard keyboard has years of dev and an army of developers behind it.

Comment: Oh, no, I'm not suggesting that you do that. I'm merely replying to the question *you* posed, i.e. what you'd have to do in order to get a keyboard to come from the side. Personally, I'm happy with Apple's standard functionality so I'll take the keyboard coming from the bottom. You won't catch *me* doing all that work! If you want a built-in option to make the keyboard come the side, feel free to file an enhancement request; Apple does listen.

Comment: That's exactly what you are suggesting: to re-implement the keyboard functionality, as a workaround for making it slide in from the side. It's not cool posting things like that just to get points and increase rep, because some poor dude might actually waste time trying them before they realize what they are doing.

Comment: No no, *you* suggested sliding the keyboard in from the side. I'm just thinking about *how* one could do that. I'm pretty sure it can't be done using the built-in keyboard, so I believe my answer is a good one. Of course, if you discover that it *can* be done using the built-in keyboard, then my answer is indeed pointless and I will stand corrected.